# If I fail a spell check to gain a combat check bonus, am I unable to equip another item?

Tags: arkham-horror

When I use my hand slot to attempt to cast a spell, and it fails, am I unable to equip a different item or spell in that hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That hand is used up for the combat round.  Next round you may equip other items/spells with that hand.

This is covered in the [FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/FAQs/Complete_Arkham_FAQ.pdf).

> **Q:** During combat, how long does a failed attempt to cast
>   a spell use up an investigator’s available hand(s)?
>
> **A:** A failed attempt to cast a spell uses the specified number
>   of hands for an entire round of combat (i.e., for one
>   iteration of combat steps 2 and 3.). In subsequent rounds
>   of combat, the investigator may switch to a new weapon
>   or try to cast a different spell.

Answer (score 0):

From page 16 of the rules,

> Note that a spell requires the number of hands printed on the card, even if the investigator fails to cast it

Sounds like a pretty definitive case for the hand(s) being used up and not equippable with any other item.